# Copying all objects (preserving their relationships) from one Realm to another

Tags: ios, swift, realm

**tl;dr: I'm trying to copy every single object from one Realm to another, but I get twice as many objects or 4 times as many objects as I should (because of their relationships, I presume).** (Edit: I actually get many many more! Check my last edit at the bottom.)

I'm trying to allow my users to backup and restore their Realm databases.

I have a `Book` class and a `ReadingSession` class. A `Book` can have many `ReadingSessions`:

```
class Book: Object {
    // (…)
    var readingSessions: [ReadingSession] {
        return linkingObjects(ReadingSession.self, forProperty: "book")
    }
}

class ReadingSession: Object {
    // (…)
    var book: Book?
}
```

To restore from the backup I tried doing this:

```
func restoreBackupFile(backupFileToRestore: String) {
    // (…) I omitted the NSFileManager related part.
    let config = Realm.Configuration(path: "\(tmp)/ReadingLog.realm", readOnly: true)
    let backupRealm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
    let defaultRealm = try! Realm()

    let results = backupRealm.objects(Book)

    try! defaultRealm.write {

        for result in results {
            defaultRealm.create(Book.self, value: result)
        }
    }
```

That copied all the `Book` objects alright, but not the `ReadingSessions` related to those `Books`.
So I added some code to copy every `ReadingSession` too:

```
    // (…)
    let bookResults = backupRealm.objects(Book)
    let sessionResults = backupRealm.objects(ReadingSession)

    try! defaultRealm.write {

        for result in bookResults {
            defaultRealm.create(Book.self, value: result)
        }
        for result in sessionResults {
            defaultRealm.create(ReadingSession.self, value: result)
        }
    }
```

And that gave my `defaultRealm` 4 times as much books as it should! I used a database with 10 books to test it out, and after running that code my default Realm had 40 books, 20 with the right `ReadingSessions` associated to them and 20 without any `ReadingSessions` at all.

I tried copying just the `ReadingSessions` to see if the related `Books` would be created too, and then I got twice as many `Books` as I should, half of them with the right `ReadingSessions` and half of them without any.

So how can I do what I want? Copy every single object from a Realm to another keeping their relationships intact and without getting duplicates like I am now?

(I know I can just replace the database files, but I want my users to be able to restore data from one database without losing the data from the other.)

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

---

**Edit:** I've been experimenting some more and it seems that if I copy just the `ReadingSessions` it creates a book for each reading session copied, even if they're related to the same book. If I have a book with 60 reading sessions, for instance, that book will be created 60 times. So my problem is even worse than I thought. When I copy the `Books` they don't come with their related `ReadingSessions`. When I copy the `ReadingSessions` they create many repeated books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create new objects on base of objects from another Realm, then linked objects are copied as well and recursed into. But backreferences are just convenience getters on your object and neither known to the schema nor accessible (for Swift), so they are not traversed at all. Even though linked objects are recursed into, they are not de-duplicated at all automatically. So this would [loop for circular relations](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1800).

You might want to configure a [primary key](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys) on `Book` and use [`create(… update: true)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6createuRdq_CS_6Object_FS0_FTMq_5valuePSs9AnyObject_6updateSb_q_) to copy your `ReadingSessions`. When you copy both, you ensure, that unread books are copied as well, if that's a valid case for your schema.

Comment: I actually want my users to be able to create duplicate books if they actively want to, that's why I didn't go for a primary key at first, but it seems like that's the way to go then, I'll just have to work around the exceptional cases. Thanks!